# TO_DATE function is not working with timezone info.

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I am trying below :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('Wed May 18 00:00:00 IST 2016', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

and expecting `18-05-2016`

But it says - 01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"

It works well if I remove IST and corresponding TZR.

What's going wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oracle DATE data type [does not have a time zone component](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG237). Neither does a plain TIMESTAMP. You need to convert to a TIMESTEMP WITH TIME ZONE:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Wed May 18 00:00:00 IST 2016',
  'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
  'DD-MM-YYYY')
FROM DUAL;
```

But IST is not a recognised time zone region, so that will still get ORA-01882: timezone region not found. You may have to explicitly replace that with a known region, e.g.:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(REPLACE('Wed May 18 00:00:00 IST 2016',
  'IST', 'Asia/Calcutta'), 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
  'DD-MM-YYYY')
FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(TO
----------
18-05-2016
```

Alternatively, if you won't be doing any manipulation on it and want the IST year anyway, you can extract the date components directly from the string, or treat IST as a fixed value and not try to interpret it at all:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('Wed May 18 00:00:00 IST 2016',
  'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS "IST" YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
  'DD-MM-YYYY')
FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(TO
----------
18-05-2016
```

... but that may not be suitable for your actual situation.